# Does Virginia Dare have an Earth-616 counterpart?

Tags: marvel, marvel-1602

In *[Marvel 1602](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_1602)*, Virginia Dare is the first child of the Roanoke Colony, who is brought to England along with her bodyguard Rojhaz. It turns out that when she is scared, she can shapeshift into a variety of animals, who are always white.

Since so many characters in *Marvel 1602* have counterparts in the mainstream Marvel universe (a.k.a. Earth-616), does Virginia Dare also have a counterpart?

I tried looking online, but pretty much everything I got results in this comic or the [real-world Virginia Dare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_Dare).

Comment: Sounds a bit like Snowbird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marvel 1602's Virginia Dare may be that world's version of [Snowbird, or "Narya,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowbird_(comics)) a Marvel hero with (among other powers) the ability to change into animals:

> Snowbird possesses a number of powers as a member of the race of superhumans known as the gods of the Native Americans of Arctic Canada. Snowbird is a metamorph who is able to change into a pale white version of any creature native to the Canadian Arctic.

The Earth-616 Snowbird seems to have little in common with Dare, beyond an origin specific North America with a colonialist theme. That being said, transforming into specifically white animals seems like an unambiguous clue that the individuals have been conflated in 1602's Virginia Dare.

Comment: Wikipedia says: "She has the ability to transform into white-furred animals when frightened, which she later learns to control, and appears to be the equivalent to Alpha Flight's Snowbird who has a similar appearance and powers, though Neil Gaiman had denied this. [citation needed]". Given that it's unsourced, I don't know if it's true.

Comment: @Thunderforge It looks like several people have _said_ that Gaiman denied this, but the quote itself is not making itself known to me. If he did say as much, then my answer is wrong—but what a weird, weird choice, to make Virginia Dare an "original character" with an existing character's visually distinct powers.

Comment: If we can't dig up proof of Neil Gaiman saying this, I would be okay accepting this answer as the most plausible, if it includes that caveat in a footnote or whatever.